# Why does xamarin android app on real device throws error always but works on simulator

Tags: android, xamarin, archiving

I have a strange problem. I have been developing an app using xamarin forms which is using an API written in php at the back end. iOS version of the app is working fine and android version is working well on simulator . When i archive and install apk file on a real device it always throws error for all the api functions. Could not find the reason, where am going wrong.

Archiving my apk file with armeabi-v7a and linking option as user and Sdk assemblies only in release mode.

Am I missing any properties to be set for archiving my project?

Any help would be appreciated.

```
        public async void OnLogin()
        {               
          string url = "http://www.example.com/UserController/login";

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            object userjson = new
            {
                email = Email.Text.ToLower(),
                password = Password.Text
            };

            var myContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userjson);
            Console.WriteLine("Post Content" + myContent);
            var buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myContent);
            var byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(buffer);
            byteContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            Console.WriteLine("Inside Login() Method");
            Console.WriteLine("Json Content::" + myContent);
            Console.WriteLine("Json Byte::" + byteContent.ReadAsStringAsync());
            var response = await client.PostAsync(url, byteContent).ConfigureAwait(false);

            var code = response.StatusCode;

            Console.WriteLine("Code::" + code);

            if (code.ToString() == "OK")
            {
                string res = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                App.serverToken = "activated";
                App.Current.Properties["Token"] = App.serverToken;
                await Application.Current.SavePropertiesAsync();
                isValid = true;
                Console.WriteLine("Token::" + App.serverToken);
               }
                else
                {
                isValid = false;
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    LoginFaild.Text = "InCorrect Email or Password";
                    Email.Text = string.Empty;
                    Password.Text = string.Empty;
                });
              }
            }
```

This is the method where am accessing API using Postasync.

Comment: First, "throws error" is not a helpful description of the problem.  We need to know which specific errors it is throwing and what code is causing them.  Second, I'd suggest that you confirm your app has Internet permissions enabled in the manifest.  This happens automatically in debug mode but must be enabled manually work in release mode.

Comment: What kind of error are you talking about? Try to build Release and plug a device to see the console.

Comment: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. This is what the error am getting only for android version @Jason

Comment: Well, check if it does it in debug mode on a real device or just when archiving. If also in debug mode, check the relevant part of code and exception itself.

Comment: Again, since you haven't bothered to post the relevant code, it's difficult to give you any further suggestions

Comment: I have posted the code @Jason